# how can i check if TLS 1.2 is enabled by script in powershell

Tags: powershell, tls1.2

Hello im using this script:

```
$key = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\'
if (Test-Path $key) {
  $TLS12 = Get-ItemProperty $key
  if ($TLS12.DisabledByDefault -ne 0 -or $TLS12.Enabled -eq 0) {
    Throw "TLS 1.2 Not Enabled"
  }
}
```

which shows if in registry files are turn into 1/0 but while im going to "internet options" and unmark checkbox "use tls 1.2" this script do not show it is mark as off.
how can i check this checkbox by script?
or that in "internet options" shows only IE settings?

Comment: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -match 'Tls12'` ??

Comment: Thanks! That's seem to be working :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is valid, but to test if it's working (rather than merely enabled) you can use...
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com -UseBasicParsing).StatusDescription

This calls a tls1.2 specific service on azure and will return an error if TLS1.2 is enabled.

All the other answers I see online are the equivalent of saying "How can I check my car works" and being told "make sure there is fuel in the tank".
I think the advice should be to turn the key and see.  :)

Comment: I executed `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com -UseBasicParsing).StatusDescription` as suggested. This returns OK. Does it mean that the TLS1.2 is *not* enabled? You wrote, that an error will be returned if TLS1.2 is einabled. Is it correct? Or did you mean that in this case the TLS1.2 is disabled?